# [jQuery]Page refreshes after appending html with .html()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

So I'm trying to get some data from the server with php but as soon as it's loaded onto the page it seems to reload the page and make it disappear again. 
My html:

```
<form id="searchForm">
<input name="searchValue" type="text" id="search">
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Zoek op klant"          onclick="getKlanten()">
</form>

<div id="klanten">
</div>
```

My js:

```
function getKlanten(){
var value = $("#search").val();
$.ajax({
    url:'includes/getKlanten.php',
    async: false,
    type: 'POST',
    data: {'searchValue':value},
    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
    {
        $('#klanten').html(data);
    },
    error: function () {
        $('#klanten').html('Bummer: there was an error!');
    }
});
}
```

Can anyone help? It gets put into the div but then instantly disappears again.

Comment: FYI, there is no reason to set ajax request synchronously

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, avoid inline click handlers. The page reloads because by default a form submits the form content to the url specified in action attribute.

Instead attach an event to the form and use preventDefault to avoid the page from refreshing. Do something like this

```
$('#searchForm').on('submit', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  // your ajax request.
});
```

Or attach an event to input button like this

```
$('input[type="submit"]').on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();

  // your ajax request
});
```

Read more about preventDefault [here](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/)